Why does std::conditional require both branches to be defined?
I have a code that conditionaly modifies input type based on type predicate, like this:
template <typename T>
using result = std::conditional_t<type_pred<T>::value, type_cast<T>::type, T>;

It compiles only if T satisfies type_cast's constraints (regardless of the result of type_pred<T>::value).
As an example, in the following code std::make_unsigned_t requres T to be integral, so compiler complains if T is not.
template <typename T>
using make_unsigned_if_integral_t =
    std::conditional_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, std::make_unsigned_t<T>, T>;

// this works
static_assert(std::is_same_v<make_unsigned_if_integral_t<int>, unsigned int>);
// compiler complains on this
using expect_float = make_unsigned_if_integral_t<float>;

If type_cast implementaion does not constraint its param, the approach works well, e.g:
// no constraints on T here, so custom_make_unsigned<float>::type is valid (but never actually used)
template <typename T> struct custom_make_unsigned {
    template <typename U> struct impl {
        using type = U;
    };

    template <std::signed_integral U> struct impl<U> {
        using type = std::make_unsigned_t<U>;
    };

    using type = typename impl<T>::type;
};

template <typename T>
using custom_make_unsigned_if_integral_t =
    std::conditional_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, typename custom_make_unsigned<T>::type, T>;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<custom_make_unsigned_if_integral_t<float>, float>);


The question is, why does std::conditional require both branches to be "valid" and what part of the c++ language (or standard library) defines such behaviour?

This is just the conclusion of how templates work. For std::conditional It is not a good or desirable requirement by any means.

Does not answer the question, but if C++17 (or best C++20) is available, I would try to use if constexpr instead of std::conditional, possibly along with a concept.

sloppy speaking, its because SFINAE cannot happen on the isntantiation. For any template Foo you can only instantiate Foo<A,B> when A and B are valid. SFINAE works by not instantiating certain specializations. In your case its either the general impl or the specializad impl<U> for Us that are std::signed_integrals that gets instantiated.

Say if you have a template<typename X, typename Y> class A{}; then you cannot instantiate A<*some nonsense*, int> - that's just basics. std::conditional and other type traits is a kind of abuse of templates and classes to add a simple feature that C++ lacks. Of course, it comes with a bunch of downsides, as templates weren't designed for this.

@prapin As far as I know if constexpr has the same limitation.

@ALX23z, but I don't need to instantiate the "wrong" branch.

No. It is possible to use if constexpr to do what you want. template<class T> auto make_unsigned_if_integral_helper() { if constexpr(std::integral<T>) return std::make_unsigned_t<T>(T{}); else return T{}; },  and then use decltype(make_unsigned_if_integral_helper<float>())

The implementation doesn't know which branch is wrong. It doesn't have this concept of "wrong branch" at all.

if constexpr has the limitation that it works in a template, by not instatiating evrything. In an ordinary function, it still requires all branches to be valid.

Every single template class in an expression will be instantiated as part of evaluation of the expression.

Problem with false case in conditional_t being compiled and evaluated and std::conditional compile-time branch evaluation and Generic way of lazily evaluating (short-circuiting) with std::conditional_t


The question is, why does std::conditional require both branches to be "valid"?

You see it as branch, but instantiation happens before the resolution of std::conditional<..>::type.
It is similar to
int f(bool b, int n1, int n2) { return b ? n1 : n2; }

and
int n1 = 42;
int* n2 = nullptr;
f(true, n1, *n2); // UB with derefencing nullptr

Workaround is extra indirection:
template <typename T>
using result =
    typename std::conditional_t<
        type_pred<T>::value,
        type_cast<T>,
        std::type_identity<T>
    >::type;


@463035818_is_not_an_ai type_identity without type is the whole point of the fix. Note ::type is after the closing >.

This is not specific to std::conditional. Consider for example
 template <typename A, typename B>
 struct Foo {};

You can only instantiate Foo<A,B> when A and B are types (in this example they need no definition, but they must be declared).
The only way to allow "invalid" types is by not instantiating certain specalizations. SFINAE does that. An example from cppreference:

template<class T>
int f(typename T::B*);
 
template<class T>
int f(T);
 
int i = f<int>(0); // uses second overload


In a nutshell, substition of the template argument in the first template fails when T is int, because int::B makes no sense. This is not an error, but the compiler continues and simply discards that overload. (Hence, the name Substitution Failure Is Not An Error). Only during substitution of the template argument such failure is not an error.
If you write for example
int i = f<int::B>(0);  

this is just a hard error.

Your custom_make_unsigned_if_integral_t does not make use of SFINAE, but it uses a concept to select the "right" specialization. using type = std::make_unsigned_t<U>; is never instantiated for any T that does not satisfy the std::signed_integral concept. There is no substition failure nor any invalid type.

All type arguments to a template should be instantiated, before the instantiation of the template itself. std::conditional_t is not an exception. I have seen adhoc solutions involving lambdas and if constexpr but the simplest, most readable solution is explicit specialization. I was never good at old school adhoc SFINAE, so I present the simpler C++20 constraint template implementation:
template<typename T>
struct my_trait: std::type_identity<my_else_t<T>> {};

template<typename T>
requires my_test<T>::value
struct my_trait: std::type_identity<my_if_t<T>> {};

template<typename T>
using my_trait_t = typename my_trait<T>::type;

Notice that a template type aliase(my_trait_t) cannot be explicitly specialized; therefore We need to define my_trait first.
Upon trying to instantiate my_trait<T>, the compiler first evaluates my_test<T>::value then peeks the correct definition. It is possible to totally avoid the alias and trait syntactic noise, iff we are defining a type which is not an aliase:
template<typename T>
class my_type: {/*"else" definition*/};

template<typename T>
requires my_test<T>::value
class my_type: {/*"if" definition*/};

This is because unlike aliase type templates, all other template definitions(including class definitions) can be explicitly specialized. IMO " Less is more." is a key idiom in modern C++ programming; it's best to try to express everything in the simplest imaginable form. It may take more time to think the design through, but it is worth readability and maintainability that follows.
